# Finding chained, incremented values in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to find all values in an array that would form a chain of incremented values - all referencing back to a certain starting value. Increments can go both "up" and "down".

```
array = [10, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11]
```

Starting with the number `2` should return:

```
[2, 3]
```

Starting with the number `10` should return:

```
[9, 10, 11]
```

There are of course plenty of inefficient ways of doing this, but I'm asking this here because doing this efficiently is important for my case and I'm such a JS newbie.

Comment: while this question is neat, you could add some examples what you have already tried. please take a look here: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.includes()` to check if a number exists in an array. If the number is before the base reference add it using `unshift`, if after add it using `push`:

```js
var array = [10, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11];

function findChain(array, num) {
  if(!array.includes(num)) {
    return [];
  }
  
  const result = [num];
  let before = num - 1;
  let after = num + 1;
  
  while(array.includes(before)) {
    result.unshift(before--);
  }
  
  while(array.includes(after)) {
    result.push(after++);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log('Ref 2 -', findChain(array, 2));

console.log('Ref 5 -', findChain(array, 5));

console.log('Ref 10 -', findChain(array, 10));

console.log('Ref 20 -', findChain(array, 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution :

```
var array = [10, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11, 14, 89, 12, 8];

var trouver = nombre => {
  var result = [];
  if (array.indexOf(nombre) !== -1) result.push(nombre);
  else return result;
  for(var chiffre = nombre+1; array.indexOf(chiffre) !== -1; chiffre++) result.push(chiffre);
  for(var chiffre = nombre-1; array.indexOf(chiffre) !== -1; chiffre--) result.push(chiffre);
  return result.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}

console.log(trouver(9)); //[ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be a double chained list for it.

```js
function getValues(array, value) {
    var object = Object.create(null),
        result,
        o;
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        object[a] = object[a] || { value: a, pre: object[a - 1] || null, succ: object[a + 1] || null };
        if (object[a - 1]) {
            object[a - 1].succ = object[a];
        }
        if (object[a + 1]) {
            object[a + 1].pre = object[a];
        }
    });
    o = object[value];
    if (o) {
        result = [];
        while (o.pre) {
            o = o.pre;
        }
        while (o.succ) {
            result.push(o.value);
            o = o.succ;
        }
        result.push(o.value);
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [10, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11, 14, 89, 12, 8];

console.log(getValues(array, 2));
console.log(getValues(array, 10));
console.log(getValues(array, 42));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

1. Sort the array first
2. Iterate array items one by one, keep pushing the *start-counter* if *current-item* value is not bigger than *last-item* by **1**, else reset the `start-counter` to *current-index*.

For Example :

```js
 var arr = [10, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11];

 function getAllSequences(arr) {
   arr.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a - b
   });

   var startIndex = 0;
   var endIndex = 0;
   var lastItem = 0;
   var chains = [];
   arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
     if (index > 0) {
       if ((item - lastItem) > 1) {
         extractChain(chains, arr, startIndex, endIndex);
         startIndex = index;
       } else {
         endIndex = index;
         if (index == arr.length - 1) {
           extractChain(chains, arr, startIndex, endIndex);
         }
       }
     }
     lastItem = item;
   });
   return chains;
 }



 console.log(getAllSequences(arr));

 function extractChain(chains, arr, startIndex, endIndex) {
   var value = arr.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
   if (value.length > 0) {
     chains.push(value);
   }
 }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz Hmm, I thought as long as number of items are in 5 digits, sorting shouldn't hurt. https://jsfiddle.net/cp0kgozm/

Comment: @NinaScholz how are the numbers with double chained list?

Comment: i take them as string, but store the value. i could store the index as well, but the value is enough to get the wanted result back.